# XOR Encryption of two files to third file

Tags: c, encryption, xor

I am trying to do it based on this tutorial:
http://forum.codecall.net/topic/48889-c-tutorial-xor-encryption/

But I did not come to a function that after double encryption gives me the same file.
I tried a lot of versions and corrects and non of them worked for me.
Here is my current code:

```
void encrypt (FILE* in, FILE* out, FILE* key){
    int a,b;
    while ((a = fgetc(in)) != EOF){

        if ((b = fgetc(key)) == EOF){
            rewind(key);
            b = fgetc(key);
        }
        int d = a^b;
        printf("%c XOR %c is %c\n",a,b,d);


        fputc(d,out);

    }
    printf("end of encrypt\n");
}
```

Someone knows what and how to change it so it will work?

You can ignore the prints, of course.

Full code as requested: http://pastebin.com/4GHgb9gw (not long, 53 lines).

Comment: Post how files were opened (Hint: should it be text or binary)?

Comment: try with `d` as `char` and not `int`

Comment: @chux, i thought of the same thing, but the example that he posted uses `char` and opens `file` normally.

Comment: @Haris Relevant information should be posted here - not elsewhere.  I tend to avoid such links.

Comment: Does it work if the input file has less characters than the key file? When trying to decrypt, did you reopen the key file or use it as it was after encryption?

Comment: @Haris  Appears OP is opening file is text mode and should be in binary.  This is critical on some OS's.

Comment: What happened when you tried this with a small file of known data and you stepped through with your debugger, checking char-by-char?

Comment: added how i open the files as requested

Answer (score 1):

It looks like to me that you need to rewind your key file.

Your main looks like:

```
int main(){
    FILE* out = fopen("out.txt", "ab+");
    if (out == NULL){
        out = fopen("scores.dat", "wb");
    }
    FILE* in = fopen("in.txt", "rb");
    FILE* key = fopen("key.txt", "rb");
    FILE* end = fopen("end.txt", "ab+");
    if (end == NULL){
        end = fopen("scores.dat", "wb");
    }

    encrypt(in,out,key);   
    // Need to rewind key file and out file again before re-processing.
    encrypt(out,end,key);
    return(0);
}
```

When you open the key file it is starting at beginning of file.

So when you do the second encrypt you need to rewind it so that it starts from beginning of file again before processing the encrypted.  That way the same sequence of exclusive ORs will be done in the same, duplicated steps.

Comment: I still get an empty "end" file. current code: http://pastebin.com/7kJ91E9m
(sorry for not pasting it here, i tried but failed).

Comment: Success! i just needed to rewind all of the files! thank you all!

Comment: @GumBi: You need to rewind the `out` and `key` files.  However, since the first call to `encrypt()` doesn't modify/move the `end` file, that doesn't need to be rewound; similarly, since you don't reuse the `in` file, that doesn't need to be rewound either.